# Adopt the code from js6 to js5

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I want to use this sample code but I need to use javaScript5 and not 6, since we are working on node 0.12.7 and cannot upgrade now.
(I use bluebird)

This is the code in js6

```
    checkAppPort: function(port, retriesLeft) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


                this.checkPortStatus(port, host).then(resolve, error => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft - 1).then(resolve, reject);
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

now I've changed it to the following  but I got error

> [ReferenceError: resolve is not defined]

```
return new Promise(resolve, reject), function () {
        this._checkPortStatus(port, HOST).then(resolve, error), function () {
            console.log("Waiting for App to start: checking port: " + port + " attempt: " + retriesLeft);
            setTimeout(function () {

                this.checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft - 1).then(resolve, reject);

            }, 1000);
        }
    };
},
```

Comment: have you tried babel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your ES2015 code through babel yields

```
checkAppPort: function checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft) {
    var _this = this;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        _this.checkPortStatus(port, host).then(resolve, function (error) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                _this.checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft - 1).then(resolve, reject);
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

---

> The ideal solution would be to change your ES2015 to avoid the new Promise blah blah blah

---

As you have tagged with Bluebird

```
checkAppPort: function checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft) {
    var _this = this;

    return this.checkPortStatus(port, host)["catch"](function (error) {
        return retriesLeft > 0 ? Promise.delay(1000, function () {
            return _this.checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft - 1);
        }) : Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

I believe that is equivalent code (ES5) - the ES6 version is

```
checkAppPort: function (port, retriesLeft) {
    return this.checkPortStatus(port, host)
    .catch(error => retriesLeft > 0 ? Promise.delay(1000, () => this.checkAppPort(port, retriesLeft - 1)) : Promise.reject(error))
}
```

I think that's probably not the "tightest" version of the code either though

> to answer the comment

In ES5

```
checkAppPort: function checkAppPortAlt(port, retries) {
    var _this = this;

    var checkit = function checkit(retriesLeft, retry) {
        if (retry) {
            console.log("Retry ...", retry);
        }
        return _this.checkPortStatus(port, host)["catch"](function (error) {
            return retriesLeft > 0 ? Promise.delay(1000, function () {
                return checkit(retriesLeft - 1, retry + 1);
            }) : Promise.reject(error);
        });
    };
    return checkit(retries, 0);
}
```

In ES2016 that is

```
checkAppPortAlt: function (port, retries) {
    var checkit = (retriesLeft, retry) => {
        if(retry) {
            console.log("Retry ...", retry);
        }
        return this.checkPortStatus(port, host)
        .catch(error => retriesLeft > 0 ? Promise.delay(1000, () => checkit(retriesLeft - 1, retry + 1)) : Promise.reject(error))
    };
    return checkit(retries, 0);
}
```

Not tested, but possibly correct :D - I am worried about the correctness of `this` in the ES2015 code - though, babel seems to translate it to something that should work in ES5

Comment: Thanks 1+ one last question, I put the retires number which user can define as 10 but in the console I want to write someting like "checking port" attempet number 1 ...2 and so on how would you suggest to do it ? start from 1 just for console until max retires...

Answer (score 1):

You have some strange syntax going on there. Like you're trying to invoke `new Promise(resolve, reject)` and `.then(resolve, reject)` (even though valid, is not what you want).

You should be doing the following:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  this._checkPortStatus(port, HOST).then(resolve, function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

I just fixed your function calls to receive `resolve` and `reject` as parameters of those functions.

---

Also, as commented by @Jaromanda X, you better try [Babel](http://babeljs.io) to transpile your code from ES6 to ES5, so you don't deal with such problems anymore when converting JS code.

Comment: having `.then(resolve, reject)` can be fine (it works in this case if you read the code and what it does)

Comment: Yeah, the code is just fine, but the syntax is strange!